# Headless Browser for FreeBSD Server?

Tags: freebsd, headless-browser

I'm looking for an open source headless browser to run on a FreeBSD shared Web server, which can do reasonably accurate rendering of current HTML/CSS/JS.

As I'm not very skillfull with Unix/servers and don't have root access, this should have no dependencies that would not be installed on a typical Apache shared Web hosting server (ruling out Java and HtmlUnit I believe), and should ideally even be pre-compiled for FreeBSD.

I guess I need a command-line and/or PHP-accessible interface (I'm not too clear on how any of that will work).

Please respond to this question if:

- you're already familiar with this new trend in Web dev of rendering things server-side with headless browsers (e.g. page previews, Google-friendly AJAX indexing, etc.)
- and you have some software to recommend for my needs

Thanks

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4719902/real-headless-browser

Answer (score 3):

I like **lynx**, it's a bit limited but unbelievably fast.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe http://phantomjs.org/ is worth to have a look at.

Another way is to remote control the real browser using for example

http://www.seleniumhq.org/