# Are there implementations of the W3C DOM other than in web browsers?

Tags: api, dom, w3c

So we all know that the [`DOM` (Document Object Model)](http://www.w3.org/DOM/) is an interface that represents HTML pages in web browsers and that you can interact with it using JavaScript.

And now and then I read comments about needing a web browser to use the DOM. But is this true?

**Aren't there other implementations of the DOM such as in server side JavaScript engines, screen scrapers, unit testing frameworks, other programming languages besides JavaScript, etc?**

Or has this really never been done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> And now and then I read comments about needing a web browser to use the DOM. But is this true?

Of course not. Your understanding is correct.

Comment: Forgive me, but this is the kind of telegraphic, zero-informatio-content anti-answer that causes lots of irritation in novice users (like me) trying to learn a bit more.

Comment: @heltonbiker so flag it as "should be a comment." FWIW, it did apparently answer the OP's question.

Comment: Well I thought it might be an unexciting question that got few views or answers so I accepted the one that did come in ... but I agree with @heltonbiker that a more fleshed-out answer would certainly be better. Maybe some examples, clarifications, limitations, etc. I don't know for sure any extra information to add or I would flesh it out myself ...

Answer (score 1):

The term you're looking for is "[headless browser](http://blog.arhg.net/2009/10/what-is-headless-browser.html)" and yes they do exist. No need to spin up an instance of IE, Chrome, or firefox to execute JavaScript and mine data from the DOM. Check out [Phantom.js](http://phantomjs.org/) or [Zombie.js](http://zombie.labnotes.org/).

Plenty of other questions related to this topic:

- [Real headless browser](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4719902/402706)
- [Headless Browser for Python (Javascript support REQUIRED!)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6025082/402706)
- [headless internet browser?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/814757/402706)

Comment: Actually headless browsers are still web browsers, though they're very interesting and useful. But the DOM can be implemented without any browser at all, such as in the [tag:jsdom] module for node.js