# How to build a complete, cross-platform and full automated test-suite for PHP/Ajax applications?

Tags: php, wordpress, joomla, automated-tests, integration-testing

I'm trying to build a full test suite for Joomla and others. There are some docs around but they're quite limited and I'm wondering somebody did wrote already some scripts. By 'full' I do mean really a complete testing  : 
1. installing an extension on Windows, Max, Linux (Vagrant, VM)
2. configuring the extensions with the CMS option panels
3. doing things in a full Ajax application

I guess I'll end up with lots of bash-scripts, triggering other scripts within a virtual setup, right ?

I must admit, I am not really familiar with all this testing frameworks and products and I'd be already very happy to get pointed to anything. Doing pure unit tests doesn't seem enough given the nature of such systems (namespace collision, interfering plugins,...)

Thank you for any hints

Answer (score 2):

I am not familiar with `wordpress` and `joomla` but those are just PHP code, so using `PHPUnit` can be suitable. With `PHPUnit` you are not only doing unit testing but you can also do other kinds of tests (it depends on how much time you are willing to spend on testing but I would say that it can cover pretty much any aspects)

As for front-end testing, there are several choices

- Using `selenium` to write tests
- Using one of the many headless testing frameworks out there (for instance, casperjs in Javascript, Watir for Ruby etc...)

For setting up virtual environment, apart from `vagrant` you can check `docker`

Answer (score 1):

There are many programs you can use to do the normal interaction tests; if you want to handle logins, some scripting will be necessary to grab the token.

But for a full integration test including ajax I guess you'd be better off with a headless browser, take a look at this [Real headless browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4719902/real-headless-browser/4720110#4720110) where the same requirement is discussed in detail